# What are orthogonal projection, tangential gradient and divergence on a manifold?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, field-theory, manifolds

I read a handout discussing the orthogonal projection, tangential gradient and divergence on a manifold:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a hypersurface embedded in a manifold. For the sake of simplicity, we just assume $\Gamma$ to be a closed curve, for example, a circle in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $n$ be the vector field of normals on $\Gamma$, and $T_x\Gamma$ be the tangent space of $\Gamma$, such that $\|n\|=1$ and $n \perp T_x\Gamma$.
>
> Now we want to define a tangential gradient $\nabla_\Gamma$ and a tangential divergence $\nabla_\Gamma^T$ for a differentiable function $f$ on $\Gamma$. Thus we can introduce an orthogonal projection $P$ onto $T_x\Gamma$, such that $P=I-nn^T$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then we have
>   \begin{align}
> \nabla_\Gamma f = P \nabla f = (I - n n^T)f \\
> \nabla_\Gamma^T f = \mathrm{tr}(\nabla_\Gamma f) = \nabla^T(f - n^T f n)
> \end{align}
>   where $\mathrm{div}()$ is denoted by $\nabla^T()$.

Q1: What is $n n^T$ and how to image $P=I - n n^T$?

Q2: Why the trace of $\nabla_\Gamma f$ equals to the divergence of $f$, i.e. $\nabla_\Gamma^T f = \mathrm{tr}(\nabla_\Gamma f)$?

Q3: Why the $n$ and $n^T$ exchange their positions and $f$ sits between them, i.e. $\nabla_\Gamma^T f = \nabla^T(f - n^T f n)$?

I have just learned calculus, linear algebra and elementary analysis but never study manifolds and differential geometry. Please answers these question as simple as possible, with particular examples. Thanks!

Comment: $nn^T$ is the rank 1 tensor spanning the local normal space. Given that $|n|=1$, $P=I-nn^T$ is it's complement. That is, the local rank $N-1$ tangent space of the manifold.

Comment: What do you mean $n^T$ and $n$ commute? $n^Tfn$ is an inner product. In some sense taking the part of $f$ in the $n$ direction. $nn^T$ is a matrix and $n^Tn$ a scalar which are different types of objects so they can't commute.

Comment: @mathreadler I mean $n$ and $n^T$ exchange their positions and $f$ sits between them, i.e.  $n^T f n$ in the last expression, while originally we have $n n^T$. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Commutation means that if $a$ and $b$ commute then $ab=ba$ in our case it would mean $nn^T=n^Tn$. It seems you are lacking some algebra too.